# Best way to allow and control cache

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, cache-control, yslow

**YSlow**
I was testing some of my websites using Yahoo's YSlow and noticed the following comment:
`Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources`

**My .htacces file contains the following code:**

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
```

Is this the best way to do it? And Why does YSlow advice you to set the cache for at least one week?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the HTML5 Boilerplate project, which has a fairly well commented .htaccess file that includes cache related directives https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does YSlow advice you to set the
>   cache for at least one week?

Because they consider *(and it's not a bad idea)* that one day is not quite long enough : if you have some user that comes to your website only a couple of times per week, a cache of 1 day will not be useful for him.

Instead, the basic idea is to cache *forever* -- and to change the URL *(changing the name of the file, typically)* when a file is modified, to force the browse to download the new version.

Comment: ...and although browsers **should** understand about timezones, a lot of them don't

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks for your response! What if I prefer not to change the filename everytime I edit a file? Would it be a good idea to use ETags? Or are they not reliable?

Comment: As far as I remember, E-Tags are not always the best solution *(especially when you have more than one server)* ;; caching the file forever, and changing the it's name is actually the best solution I know -- of course, you'll need to find a way to automate this ;-)

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks you. What kind of files will be cached? HTML, CSS, JS and images? And how do I set the cache forever?

Comment: I generally cache "static" files : CSS, JS, and images. "forever" ? Well, I year is pretty much longer than forever, when it comes to Internet ;-)

Comment: I usually use some kind of cachebusting code, so I don't have to change the file name everytime. Something like `js.js?v=<?php echo filemtime('js.js'); ?>`

Comment: @Thai: Is this really faster? Because you will need to call the function everytime you load the website.

Comment: @Michiel I actually have a deployment script that updates the `index.html` with the right timestamps, so I never have to worry about performance. :)

Comment: @Thai: That's awesome! I have one more question. Would you recommend using ETags too? Please have a look at my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180135/website-with-optimal-cache-control