# Website with optimal cache control

Tags: php, caching, .htaccess, header

**My goal**

I would like to let browsers cache my whole website, but only download the static content when I have changed one or more files.

**My situation**
After some research I have found a way to do this. That is to add a `Far Future Expires Header` to my htaccess file and add a querystring to my files using the `filemtime()` function.

**The problem**

When I click on the address bar and type in my website address in firefox, then Firebug displays 
`38.3 KB (36.4 KB from cache)`

When I press F5 in firefox, then Firebug displays:
`241.1 KB (10.9 KB from cache)`

Now I have tried to do the same with Google and they are sending HTTP header 304 back. I have read a lot about ETag and the Last Modified header, but I have heard a lot of people saying that they are not really reliable.

**My question**

What would be the best solution if I would like to send HTTP header 304 back with my static content if the user presses on F5, like Google?

I am asking this question because I am often visiting a website and using F5 to see if there is some new information available. Not to reload the images etcetera.

**Update**

It seems that Firefox is controlling the way the cache is used and I would like to use the cache also when a user presses F5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very purpose of **reload** is to reload the page. There is no server-side header magic if the browser was witten to ignore caches when the user specifically asks for it.

The solution for Google is that you check if the crawler sent an If-Modified-Since header with:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
    exit();
}
```

This trick could work for browsers, but not in *forced reload* modes, like Firefox's SHIFT+RELOAD.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. What I mean is that I am often visiting a website and using F5 to see if there is some new information available. Not to reload the images etcetera. And secondly, this is PHP code. How can I use it for my static content (e.g. images)?

Comment: For your static content apache's `mod_expires` should do the trick. Also if browsers send the If-Modified_Since header, apache will reply with the 304 (or at least I would be supreised it if was not).

Comment: you could maybe find some .htaccess rules. just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the newer application cache feature.
I don't know what your target browser is, but most browsers have been supporting it for quite a few versions so far..
This way you can define your statics to be downloaded only once.

For some very good information on the subject you can take a look at this page:
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am concerned about the IE users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the intent of your question, but you can specify the response code in php, with the header function, regardless of whether or not your user presses a button.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I know that, but how do I do that for my images, CSS etcetera?